# Java Applet, Displaying current time and String that changes every 30 seconds

Tags: java, applet

This applet displays time and a string that changes every 30 seconds to another string, there are 5 such strings.

the problem is during execution the strings don't change as they are supposed to. They usually skip the order.

I would like to know what's wrong with this approach?

```
package applet;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Project1 extends Applet implements Runnable  {
    String[] str = new String[4];
    int index=0;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread t,t1;

       public void start(){
           setSize(getMaximumSize());
      t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();

      str[0] = "Hope for the best, but prepare for the worst.";
      str[1] = "You can't judge a book by its cover.";
      str[2] = "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you.";
      str[3] = "Practice makes perfect.";
       }
   public void run(){
      t1 = Thread.currentThread();


      while(t1 == t){
         repaint();
         try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);    
         }
         catch(InterruptedException e){}
      }
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
      int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
      if(sec ==30 ||sec == 60){
          ++index;

      }
      if(index > 4) index =0;
      g.drawString(str[index], 400, 300);

       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss aa");
       String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString();
       g.drawString(formattedDate,800,30);

       g.drawString("Counter: " + (index+1), 600, 400);


   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

java Thread::sleep(int millisecond) didn't sleep for exactly time you pass to it, instead it sleep "at least millisecond".
And repaint didn't will be call to invalidate your view instantly. It call paint whenever it want.
And paint method can be call multiple time per second.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you tell me the correct way to do it.